# Error when binding 2D Array to Gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, arrays, gridview, multidimensional-array

I want to bind a multidimensional array to gridview, but it display the following error when running "`Gridview1.DataBind()`"

"Array was not a one-dimensional array."

The following is my code:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        CreateArray()
End Sub

Private Sub CreateArray()

        Dim Array(4, 3) As String
            Array(0, 0) = "ABC"
            Array(1, 0) = "DEF"
            Array(2, 2) = "GHJ"
            Array(1, 3) = "XVZ"

        Gridview1.DataSource = Array       
        Gridview1.DataBind() 

End Sub
```

Is there any mistake in my code ? Thanks,

Joe

Answer (score 2):

You can't bind a `2D Array` to a `Gridview`. It should be either a `Single Dimensional array`, a `DataTable`, or a `Collection` to bind data to a GridView.

Answer (score 1):

Use a DataTable instead of the MultiDimmensional array.  These will bind nicely to a GridView (or other data controls).

http://www.issociate.de/board/goto/880762/Binding_Multidimensional_Array_to_DataGrid.html

Comment: Accept it if you got solution.